# How does Spring integration manages Async Gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have configured below gateway. This act as an entry point to SI flow from a web application service layer deployed on tomcat. The invoke method would be called from the service layer. The SI flow has a number of components, it uses splitters, routers, and aggregators and finally response is sent to the outputChannel.

With in SI flow, I am using number of task-executors to have certain flows to run in parallel (specially after splitter).

How does SI ensure that it returns the correct response back to the call from service layer? Is there a possibility where response from one user request may be sent to other request? If yes, does it require any special handling? I can paste the full configuration if needed.

```
<!-- Entry point Facade to DSL layer. To be called by Liquidity Portal web application -->
<int:gateway id="dslServiceFacade" service-interface="dsl.gateway.IDSLServiceFacade"  
    default-request-channel="inputChannel" default-reply-channel="outputChannel" error-channel="errorChannel" async-executor="dslParallelExecutor">
    <int:method name="invoke" request-channel="inputChannel" request-timeout="5000"/>
</int:gateway>

public interface IDSLServiceFacade {

public Future<DSLResponseVO> invoke(Map<String, Object> requestMap) throws LSIntegrationException;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each gateway request gets a new temporary channel (in the `replyChannel` header). When you explicitly use a reply channel on the gateway, it is bridged to the actual reply channel for the request. The calling thread waits to receive a reply on that channel.

In general, you can omit the reply channel and simply have no `output-channel` on the final endpoint. The framework will detect that and route the reply directly to the `replyChannel` header, back to the gateway.

Sometimes it's desirable to use an explicit reply channel (for example if you want to wire tap it for logging); in these situations, the framework does the bridging I mentioned above.

It is critical that the `replyChannel` header is not removed by the flow; otherwise the framework has no way to get the reply back to the caller.